# minimum value of vector expression

Tags: vector-analysis, maxima-minima

If $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are unit vectors and $\vec{c}$ satisfies  $$\vec{c}=-\vec{a}-(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})\vec{b} -\vec{a} \times\vec{b}$$ 
Then the minimum absolute value of  $(\vec{a} \times\vec{c} ) \cdot \vec{b}$

my attempt--

$(\vec{a} \times\vec{c} ) \cdot \vec{b}$ can be written down as  $\vec{a} \cdot(\vec{c}  \times \vec{b})$ and thus i calculated $\vec{c}  \times \vec{b}$ and then took the dot product with $\vec{a}$ but could not proceed to find out the minimum value.Please help me with this one.Thanks.

Comment: By $\vec{a}*\vec{c}$ do you really mean $\vec{a}\times\vec{c}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We start to simplify the expression for $(\vec{a} \times\vec{c} ) \cdot \vec{b}$ using properties of [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product):

$$(\vec{a} \times\vec{c} ) \cdot \vec{b}=$$

$$(\vec{a} \times (-\vec{a}-(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})\vec{b} -\vec{a} \times\vec{b}) ) \cdot \vec{b}=$$

$$(- \vec{a} \times \vec{a}-(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})(\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) -\vec{a}\times(\vec{a} \times\vec{b})) \cdot \vec{b}=$$

$$(-(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})(\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) - \vec{a}(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})+\vec{b}(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a}) ) \cdot \vec{b}=$$

$$-(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})((\vec{a} \times \vec{b})\cdot \vec{b}) - (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})+(\vec{b}\cdot \vec{b}) (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a})=$$

$$(\vec{b}\cdot \vec{b}) (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a}) - (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}).$$

The last expression is the left hand side of [Cauchy-Shwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality) for vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, so it is at least zero and it is zero iff the vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are parallel, in case of their unit length iff $\vec{a}=\pm \vec{b}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$(\vec{a} \times\vec{c} ) \cdot \vec{b} = -(\vec{c} \times\vec{a} ) \cdot \vec{b}
   = \vec{a}\cdot(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})+(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\vec{b}\times(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}) + (\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\cdot(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}).$$
Simplify the first two terms.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you need to use the identity
\begin{equation}
A\times(B\times C)=(A \cdot C) B- (A \cdot B) C\, .
\end{equation}